# What is "preview of quality rollup"

Tags: wsus, windows-update

Microsoft puts out different versions of rollups/patches monthly via WSUS. One really bizarre one is "Preview of quality rollup for .Net framework". Preview? WTF does that mean? It appears to be an installable patch bundle like the others, but it's name has preview. How could I preview an installation by installing it? So, there is also "security only update for .Net framework" and I think there's a "security and quality rollup for .Net framework". So, there's "security and quality rollup", "security only update", and "preview of quality rollup". Microsoft couldn't make this any more confusing. And even though some appear to be a subset of others, I can select to install all of them. What happens if I do? 
I clicked the "more information" thing and it says nothing to describe what this means. I Googled and found nothing. Can anyone explain (particularly "preview" WTF!?) or point me to a good article? Thanks!!!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/824684/description-of-the-standard-terminology-that-is-used-to-describe-micro

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[A "preview of monthly rollup" patch is just what it says.  A preview.  Of a monthly rollup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/824684/description-of-the-standard-terminology-that-is-used-to-describe-micro).

> Definition: A tested, cumulative set of new updates that are packaged together and distributed over Windows Update, WSUS, System Center Configuration Manager and Microsoft Update Catalog ahead of the release of the next Monthly Rollup for customers to proactively download, test and provide feedback. The Preview of Monthly Rollup is product specific and addresses new non-security updates, and includes fixes from the latest Monthly Rollup. This Preview of Monthly Rollup would be displayed under the title Preview of Monthly Quality Rollup when you download or install and will be classified as an "Optional" update.

Presumably, these will be included in the following monthly rollup (at least the ones that work and don't cause too many problems), so my preference is to ignore these, and let someone else fill the role of unpaid beta tester. YMMV, I suppose.